# Combine Multiple Criteria Using Filter and Array

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm in the process to make a sheet for workorder, but i had a problem when i need to combine multiple row to 1 cell.
i already can do it using copy paste to all the cells in 1 column, but can i do this to array?

[image]

This my sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZcqfDJYEINBimmXEM3h3hl9qTdUBrAKS3IBqazJfQyE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B3:B="";;REGEXREPLACE(C3:C&CHAR(10)&D3:D; "^\n"; )))
```

[image]